# Can't run JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm following tutorial cideon on `JavaScript` and wrote some examples in Notepad++ and saved them as something.html. The problem is when I open it with IE or Chrome, the code between `<script>` and `</script>` tags doesn't run at all. What is wrong with that?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example of prompt()</title>
    <script>
        var user_name;
        user_name = prompt("What is your name?");
        document.write("welcome to my page ")
            + user_name + "!");
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: document.write("welcome to my page  " + user_name +  "!"); try this

Comment: Look at the console. You will see an error there...

Comment: you have a syntax error (closing a parentheses too early)

Comment: Yeah, Sorry/ I missed that paranthesis.

Comment: @LPK, where I can find errors on console?

Comment: Press F12-Key at your page

Comment: Stop it guys. No need to post such a bunch of answers for such a little problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a syntax error in `document.write` statement.

Write it as follow

```
document.write("welcome to my page "+ user_name + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one too many ")"

```
document.write("welcome to my page " + user_name + "!");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move the script part out of the head to the body tag.

Second, write

```
document.write("welcome to my page " + user_name + "!");
```

in one line and remove the first closing parenthesis.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example of prompt()</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var user_name;
            user_name = prompt("What is your name?");
            document.write("welcome to my page " + user_name + "!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it more a problem with `document.write` in the head. and a [possible problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) with `document.write` at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you open in chrome. Press F12 or Right Click > Inspect Element. Make sure you select "Console" at the top. Pay attention and try to understand what the console tells you.

In your case, this is what it says when I paste that code into my console:

[image]

"Unexpected token" This means that it can't understand the script, it was expecting a `;` or a new line because you have a bracket at the end. Remove that and it should work.